# The Else statement variable can't store data in PHP

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    if($file_size > 2097152){
       $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

    if(empty($errors) == true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../img/images/".$file_name);
    }

} else {
    $file_name = $db_con->escape_string($_POST['image_old']); // Why this data will not stored in the file_name variable?
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @MohammadMalek PHP doesn't care https://3v4l.org/dDHDm

Comment: I tried but the result is the same.

Comment: But in the other file <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> it is working but I use action outside the file it's gone. The result is blank to my image_old.

Comment: While `Else statement variable` is a funny designation, `$file_name` being declared in each of "the `then` and `else` scopes" may well be your problem - especially if you try to use it after the *if-then-else*. That said, handle large data like images or files as *large data* rather than text/strings, using files or PDOs instead of literals represented as strings.

Comment: @greybeard - Your comment is very unclear. Why would declaring a variable in both the if and the else-block be the OP's problem? Why would it be a problem at all?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` in your else-block and check if it contains what you expect.

Comment: My goal is if I upload an image the file_name would be the new image. But if is not set the name of the old image would be replaced the file_name variable but I am stuck .. It returns blank.. I don't know why I think that was correct and besides it is running on the other file. I am frustrated right now what is the best option? Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

> Why this data will not stored in the file_name variable?

Because `isset($_FILES['image'])` is always true in form input, even if there are no files was attached.

If you want to check the case of empty images then you need to count input images.

Simplest way is just check count of elements in array with `!empty($_FILES['image'])` intead of `isset($_FILES['image'])`

But you also can check input images if they are correct files and only then go to `else` statement.

For example:

```
$countOfGoodImages = 0;
if ( !empty($_FILES['image']) ) {
  foreach ($_FILES['image'] as $imageValue) {
    if ( isImageIsGoodForMe($imageValue) ) {
      $countOfGoodImages++;
    }
  }
}

if ($countOfGoodImages) {
  // good images
} else {
  // use old images
}
```

Comment: Cool.. Thank You so much now I know ^^